# Conditional probability, In studying the causes of power failures, the following data have been gathered:

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

In studying the causes of power failures, the following data have been gathered:
10% are due to a transformer damage, 75% are due to line damage, 5% involve both
problems. Based on these percentages, find the probability that a given power failure
involves:

a) line damage given that there is transformer damage

b) transformer damage given that there is line damage

c) transformer damage but not line damage

d) transformer damage given that there is no line damage

e) transformer damage or line damage.

Now, I am familiar with conditional probabilities ( to some degree at least ) and the first thing that came to my mind for point a) was Bayes

so

$ T $ - it involves transformer damage

$ L $ - it involves line damage

$ B $ - it involves both

$$ P(L/T)=\frac{P(L)*P(T/L)}{P(T)} $$

but the problem is that I am stuck at $P(T/L)$ I have no idea from were to start and maybe this approach is not even the correct one so I would appreciate some help, maybe a hint on how to proceed...

Comment: Hint: use the definition of conditional probability

Comment: Yes but first I need a complete system of events, and I just can't think of one

Comment: Never mind, I'm such a douche we only worked with bayes and complete systems of events in my class that's why I couldn't think of a way to solve it, but I guess my answer could be found on wikipedia...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your notation, we have $\textbf{P}(T) = 0.1$, $\textbf{P}(L) = 0.75$ and $\textbf{P}(T\cap L) = 0.05$. Therefore:

(a) The sought probability is given by $\textbf{P}(L|T)$, which can be rewritten as
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(L|T) = \frac{\textbf{P}(L\cap T)}{\textbf{P}(T)} = \frac{0.05}{0.1} = 0.5
\end{align*}

(b) Analogously, we have
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(T|L) = \frac{\textbf{P}(T\cap L)}{\textbf{P}(L)} = \frac{0.05}{0.75} = \frac{1}{15}
\end{align*}

(c) Here, the event in which we are interested in is described by $\textbf{P}(T\cap L^{c})$:
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(T\cap L^{c}) = \textbf{P}(T) - \textbf{P}(T\cap L) = 0.1 - 0.05 = 0.05
\end{align*}

(d) In this case, the target event is described by $\textbf{P}(T|L^{c})$:
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(T|L^{c}) = \frac{\textbf{P}(T\cap L^{c})}{\textbf{P}(L^{c})} = \frac{\textbf{P}(T\cap L^{c})}{1 - \textbf{P}(L)} = \frac{0.05}{1 - 0.75} = \frac{0.05}{0.25} = 0.2
\end{align*}

(e) Finally, the last event is given by
\begin{align*}
\textbf{P}(T\cup L) = \textbf{P}(T) + \textbf{P}(L) - \textbf{P}(T\cap L) = 0.1 + 0.75 - 0.05 = 0.8
\end{align*}

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, in my class we only worked with Bayes and complete system of events that's why when someone just mentioned me to use the definition of conditional probability I searched on wikipedia to make sure that I'm not missing something obvious and I just realized that I was...

Comment: If you think my answer deserves it, give it a up vote.

Answer (score 1):

Going off my hint: recall that for two events $X$ and $Y$ (with $P(Y) \neq 0$) we have

$$
P(X|Y) = \frac{P(X \cap Y)}{P(Y)}
$$

So in your case, you want

$$
P(L|T) = \frac{P(L \cap T)}{P(T)}
$$

Note that the event $L \cap T$ is exactly $B$. So

$$P(L|T) = \frac{P(B)}{P(T)}$$